# How to see the Developer ID for an apk file?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I have few apk files downloaded on my system. Now I want to find their Developer ID/Creator_ID (like we have Google Inc, Facebook,etc).
I could not find that in the apk's manifest file. Does this info even exists with an apk?

I have seen that we can see the apk file information(like package name, versionCode, etc) using *'aapt.exe'* utility which is located inside the tools folder in Android SDK, but from that also I couldn't find any info regarding the Developer ID.

I have looked in the web for this but couldn't find anything significant.
Can someone help me with this..??
Thanks in advance.

Please do revert if anything is not clear above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your prompt response.
I too found a workaround for solving this issue.(One could find it a bit of overhead though, but I thought its worth sharing here.)

So one needs to first change the extension of the "apk" file to ".zip".
Then Unzip it.

There in the META-INF folder you would find a file name "Cert.RSA"
You may decode it using openssl.exe util using this command-

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -in yourRSAfile.rsa -print_certs -text
```

(For more info about this you might have to read this http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs7.html)

Now in there you may see a line providing info about the "Issuer".
Value of Tag "O" is usually the Developer ID (which is used on Google Play as well).

Hope this helps..!!

Answer (score 1):

The developer "id" in itself doesn't exist within the apk. The only existing information in an apk file is  the application's manifest, including the package name, permissions and list of activities.

The developer informations are set inside the Google Play developer console, and can be changed independently from the applications' apk.

What is unique is the package name, which usually gives information on the developer. 
For example, all my applications packages are based on my own website domain. Google's apps usually start with com.google etc...

Comment: I somewhat disagree to your statement.
By following the steps mentioned in my comment I was able to find the Developer ID from the certificate "inside the apk file".

Comment: indeed the certificate will hold a value, but as the developer id in the Google Play store may change, the value in the certificate will always stay the same, so if a company changes its name, you'll get the old one using this method.

Comment: +1 for your comment. I didn't knew it.
But still if you change your Developer ID and then try to upload an apk..will there be no conflict of certificates?
Correct me if I'm wrong. I am new to this domain.
I was going through this link- [link] (http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139626) but couldn't understand it completely. :(

Comment: The market requires that when you publish an update to your application, the new apk uses the same certificate as the first upload. This mean that the name in the certificate will always be the same. See here for info on apk certificates : https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#strategies

Answer (score 1):

If the APK is signed, you can get certificate information. It may or may not have an actual name in it, but it most probably will. Use the jarsigner command:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my.apk
```

The lines starting with 'X.509, CN=blah, blah' will have the closest thing to developer ID.